# How to check in code whether the home screen is in focus in android (across all the devices)?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, homescreen

I am trying to display floating icon in home screen. I am using the following code:

```
        List<RunningTaskInfo> runningtasks = actvityManager.getRunningTasks(1);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        String topmostapp = runningtasks.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

This works fine with the devices below Lollipop version.

For Lollipop, I am trying to use the following code:

```
          for(RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
          if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                if ((appProcess.processName.contains("launcher"))) {
                //Sets the condition.
                }
```

The problem in the code is this works fine only when the home screen package has "launcher" word like Samasung device. But in devices like Moto G, the package name is different ("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox").

So, I would like to know if there is any common code to detect whether the home screen is in focus irrespective of the devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The home screen as in the first screen of your app?

Comment: Nope. I am asking about device home screen.

Comment: Oh like if the home button is clicked and you are navigated to the home screen?

Comment: I want to show the floating icon only when the user is on home screen. So, I need to check for that.

Comment: AndroidDev90 - Any updates ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the above mentioned problem. I removed the check with hard coded package name comparison, instead I am checking for the Home screen package name and comparing that string with the top level app process name. If it matches, I am showing the tray icon. This code is for only for the version Lollipop and above.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        PackageManager localPackageManager = getPackageManager();
        Intent checkHomeInLollipopIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        checkHomeInLollipopIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        String str = localPackageManager.resolveActivity(
                checkHomeInLollipopIntent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).activityInfo.packageName;

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
            if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                if ((appProcess.processName.equalsIgnoreCase(str))) {
                    bHomeScreen = true;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I think with the latest versions of Android, you will only get information about your own app's processes?  Hence this will not work?